# How do I add points to my graph in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-graphview

So I'm new to this language, and I've learned how to make a simple graph to plot points in Android Studio. I'm currently using GraphView. What I would like to do is, add points to my graph after the user has selected a choice, or after a certain time interval. Please help me out on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use MPAndroid chart library

```
ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));

entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));

entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));

entries.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));

entries.add(new BarEntry(18f, 4));

entries.add(new BarEntry(9f, 5));


BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Call");
```

For further details check the link

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/add-charts-to-your-android-app-using-mpandroidchart--cms-23335

Also check the GitHub repository

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart